# минимальное значение double в string

Tags: c++

как преобразовать минимальное значение double в формате fixed в string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double d = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();   
std::string s;
int j = 0,  count = 0;
while(!j) {
    d *= 10;
    j = d;
    s += '0';
    ++count;
}
--count; // нулей после точки
 s[0] = '.';

std::ostringstream os;
os << d;    
std::string b = os.str();
b.erase(b.find('.'),1);

s += b;
std::cout << s; // ваш ответ
```

Обычно экспоненциальная форма(научный формат) лучше. Его можно выводить сразу:

```
 #include <iomanip>
//...
 std::cout << std::scientific 
           << std::numeric_limits<double>::min();
```

Comment: а почему в ответе до точки пусто?

Comment: @Stanislav Petrov:  если вы в программе напишете  double r = .1; компилятор это поймет как 0.1   ну а если вам так хочется отобразить  0 перед точкой, то не трудно добавить в начало строки символ...

Answer (score -1):

Ответ:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{double number = 0.10;
stringstream bla;
string str;
bla << number;
str = bla.str();
}
```

Comment: хедр `std::stringstream` называется `<sstream>`

Comment: Да и 0.10 далек от `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()`.